# Android async task running continuously and not stopping

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using an async task to set wallpaper on menu item click but it keeps on running and does not stop. Here is the code I am using:

```
class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    Context c;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    public ImageTask(Context ctx) { this.c=ctx; }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd=ProgressDialog.show(c, "Please Wait", "Setting Wallpaper...");
    }

    public void onPostExecute() {
        pd.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(c, "Wallpaper set successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        WallpaperManager wm1=WallpaperManager.getInstance(c);

        try { wm1.setBitmap(ImageFrag1.bmg1); } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and in the item selected function I am doing this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_wall: {
            /*WallpaperManager wm=WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            try{
                wm.setBitmap(bmg1);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Wallpaper set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                oast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Wallpaper not set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/
            ImageTask it1=new ImageTask(getActivity());
            it1.execute();
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Where am i going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: you are setting bitmap in `doInbackground` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `onPostExecute()` method signature is not correct and does not override a function in the `AsyncTask` superclass. The async task is not "running continuously", it's just that the progress dialog never gets dismissed.

To fix it, replace

```
 public void onPostExecute()
```

with

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
```